# How to remove matching files from directory A in directory B in the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, files, filenames, rm

I have some duplicate files in directories `A` and `B`, how could I delete the dupes in `B` using the filenames from `A` in bash?

How to do it in other shell's is a welcome bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/B
for file in ~/A/*
do
    file1=$(basename "$file")
    [ -f "$file1" ] && { echo "deleting $file1 "; rm -- "$file1"; }
done
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/dirA -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' '/path/to/dirB/{}' \; -exec echo rm -v '/path/to/dirB/{}' \;
```

In a test:

```
$ ls -1 /path/to/dirA
dupfile
file1inA

$ ls -1 /path/to/dirB
dupfile
file1inB

find /path/to/dirA -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' '/path/to/dirB/{}' \; -exec echo rm -v '/path/to/dirB/{}' \;
rm -v /path/to/dirB/./dupfile
```

note: remove `echo` which is used for dry-run.

Answer (score 1):

In one line

```
grep -f <(ls "A") <(ls "B") | xargs -I'{}' rm "B/{}"
```

but it work depends on file name only and may affect to empty subdirs. To avoid this use `find -type f -maxdepth 1` instead of `ls`.

For more secure check use @KasyA recepie.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd B

ls ../
A
B

comm <(ls ../A) <(ls ./) -1 -2 -z | xargs -0 rm
```

`comm` shows three column,

1. unique to file1(A)
2. unique to file2(B)
3. exist on both

So we drop column 1, 2 by `-1 -2`. `-z` would use NULL for delimiter. Default is `\n' newline.

When dealing with pipe and list of arbitrary string like filename, NULL delimited transfer is safe.